# How to create an instance of a integer variable?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

So I have

```
@Override
public IBlockState getActualState(IBlockState state, IBlockAccess blockAccess, BlockPos pos) 
{
    TileEntity tileEntity = blockAccess.getTileEntity(pos);
    if(tileEntity instanceof TileEntityBlender)
    {
        TileEntityBlender te = (TileEntityBlender)tileEntity;
    }
    return state.withProperty(PROPERTY_INT, );
}
```

and I need and the second argument in `withProperty` to be a integer variable that I have set in my TileEntity class `public int progress;`, so how would I create an instance of that variable? I'm not sure if I am phrasing this all entirely right but thanks in advance!

TileEntityBlender class: https://hastebin.com/waqurutahe.java

Comment: ``Integer.valueOf(42)``, ``new Integer(42)``, ``Integer.parseInt("42")``, etc...

Comment: `Integer` or `int`? Could you also show the definition of that `withProperty` method? And the whole class where `progress` is contained in, such that we can see how everything is related and how to pass things around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `return state.withProperty(PROPERTY_INT, tileEntity.progress);` or if progress is a private variable then can do `return state.withProperty(PROPERTY_INT, tileEntity.getProgress());` if you have respective getter method.

Now in Java there is a concept of `autoboxing` that is Java compiler automatically converts the primitive types to their corresponding wrapper type if and when required. Therefore, in you case it will be converted to Integer from int automatically if `withProperty` is expecting Integer.

Comment: ok, so following what you guys have said I have this now ```return state.withProperty(PROPERTY_INT, ((TileEntityBlender)tileEntity).progress);```, which I think is what I was looking for, so thx for the help guys!